# Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are sequentially compact sets in $R^n,$ then $A+B$ is sequentially compact.

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are sequentially compact sets in $R^n$, then $A+B$ is sequentially compact.

I don't think this statement is true, but I can't find any counter example for it either. I wonder if anyone can give me a hint.

Comment: Given $(a_n+b_n)$, find a subsequence $(a_{n_k}+b_{n_k})$ such that $(a_{n_k})$ converges. Then find another subsequence so that "the second terms" converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z_n\in A+B\ni z_n\to z$

then $z_n=x_n+y_n,x_n\in A,y_n\in B$

as $A,B$ are sequ. compact so there exist $x_{n_k}\to x\in A$ and $y_{n_k}\to y\in B$

so $z_{n_k}=x_{n_k}+y_{n_k}\to x+y=z\in A+B$

Answer (score 2):

Let $(c_n)=(a_n+b_n)$ a sequence in $A+B$ where $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ and $(b_n)$ a sequence in $B$. We can extract $(a_{n_k})$ from $(a_n)$ a convergent sequence in $A$ and we extract $(b_{n'_k})$ a convergent sequence in $B$ from $(b_{n_k})$ hence the sequence $(a_{n'_k}+b_{n'_k})$ is a convergent sequence in $A+B$ extracted from $(c_n)$.